# How to read tagged PDF in C# using iText 7?

Tags: c#, regex, pdf, nlp, itext

I am trying to read pieces of information from tables in PDF files in C# using iText 7.

Currently I'm using `TextRegionEventFilter` and `PdfTextExtractor` to get the text in the cells using the cell's X, Y locations.

If you have programmed it like this before you know that this sorta works if the X, Y location of your data elements stay constant in each PDF file.

But because the table's row height and column width in my PDF files keep changing, this approach won't work very well.

So, I thought if I can extract the PDF content as a string that includes the tags, then I can precisely pinpoint the pieces of information I need by parsing the raw string much like an HTML file.

To my disappointment, the PDF content I extract using `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`'s `GetResultantText` as a string doesn't contain any of the tags.

So, my question is: Is it possible to extract PDF content with tags using iText 7? I searched high and low for how to read tagged PDF in iText, but nothing comes up.

[image]